# Reflection in optical fiber

Tags: network, fiber-optics

I took a measure (OTDR) of optical fiber from the headend and I got this :

[image]

In 10.7km The optical fiber have a "reflection". This reflection is holding 500 meters. After that reflection down again in 11.2km.(above 11.2km fiber is cut down).

How can this affect the performance in network ? Can I send costumers across that fiber ? Would have I lower error bit ?

Comment: That depends on your tolerance for a loss budget.

Comment: Hi Tony. Sorry I don't understand you

Comment: `Can I send costumers across that fiber ?` is not answerable and is really a request for an opinion

Comment: Maybe you don't understand me.  My question is: are they technical documentation about this ?

Comment: The first criteria is the overall link loss. Many manufacturers of OTDR have training on how to use and interpret their units. Just don’t expect to pick up an OTDR and use it without training.

Comment: If you don't understand how much margin in loss you need to Rx, you cannot do much without Tx and Rx levels overall

Comment: Question is : Do The reflection affect the performance ? If so, how ?

Comment: Yes, the reflection does affect the performance. How much? You have the information but you’ve not shared it with us. I’d suggest you find someone local to you that can show you how to use your OTDR and will be able to determine what type of fiber, equipment etc you have.